# ChromeWorker set pointer to the memory or send big data. How?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

We trying send 500kb through ChromeWoker and get out of memory error in console.

**This code:**

```
let charArray= ctypes.ArrayType(ctypes.char);
let base641 = new charArray(9999999);

var {ChromeWorker} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm", null);
var chworker = new ChromeWorker(self.data.url("async.js"));

chworker.onmessage = function(e){
  console.error(e.data);
};

chworker.postMessage(base641);
```

return error:

```
stack:"@undefined:undefined:undefined
CuddlefishLoader/options<.load@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/cuddlefish.js:129:9
run@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js:169:9
startup/<@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js:113:7
Handler.prototype.process@resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:863:11
this.PromiseWalker.walkerLoop@resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:742:7"
```

What is undefined? Can we set pointer to the memory through ChromeWorker?

Answer (score 2):

To pass a `ctypes` array, you'd take the `address()` and post that in a message and construct another pointer from that address on the other side. This works, but is rather nasty, of course. You'd also need to make sure that garbage collection does not collect stuff while the other side it still using it!

You might be better off using `ArrayBuffer`/typed arrays which you can [pass directly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker.postMessage#Parameters), also from non-privileged code.